# Link to droid fu jar or help installing it?

Tags: android, droid-fu

Does anyone know where you can get the droid fu jar from? I have no idea how to install it from github

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install droid fu library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802126/how-to-install-droid-fu-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this library? Can you download it? If you can download it, `Right click on the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Select the Libraries Tab -> Add external JAR -> Browse you jar and add it`. Now import the library.

Answer (score 2):

Read [the Droid-Fu documentation](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu), specifically the "How do I install it?" section, which explains, step by step, precisely how to build a JAR for your use.

If you do not understand those instructions, please contact the developer, or simply do not use the library.

Also, please do not ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why its at java2s but http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddroidfu10jar.htm appears to be the correct jar. I've used it just to see if it works and it does.

Answer (score 0):

For some general explanation regarding Droid-Fu: see this [post](http://www.marcusking.me/post/2011/04/12/Droid-Fu-Android-Library.aspx)

Also, look at [ignition](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition)  now, as Droid-Fu is discontinued.